# How to build Rust from Atom IDE on MacOS?

Tags: macos, rust, atom-editor

Trying to learn Rust. Recently installed Atom but found no way yet to build and run a Rust target. I could do this in Sublime with RustEnhanced by just pressing `Cmd-B`. Installed Atom-build and build-cargo, my Rust setup should be fine since it works from Sublime (and command-line), but from Atom I only get "No build configuration exists". I thought just having build-cargo is enough, the Atom-build documentation apparently says that the build provider (build-cargo in this case) takes care of that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a way to get what I needed. Install packages `script` and `language-rust`. Then simply open a file with extension `.rs` and hit `cmd-i`; the file will be compiled and will immediately afterward run, with output displayed in the pop-up window in the lower part of the editor.